# Is there a way to synchronize binding in ReactiveUI for WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, system.reactive, reactiveui

Let's have a simple binding in ReactiveUI for WinForms.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ReactiveUI;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form, IViewFor<ViewModel>
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            ViewModel = new ViewModel();
            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Text, v => v.Text);
            //BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ViewModel.Text = "WinForm context thread text"));
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => ViewModel.Text = "Cross-thread text");
        }

        object IViewFor.ViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return ViewModel;
            }
            set
            {
                ViewModel = (ViewModel) value;
            }
        }

        public ViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
    }

    public class ViewModel: ReactiveObject
    {
        private string _text;

        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return _text;
            }
            set
            {
                this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _text, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Setting the ViewModel.Text property in *OnLoad()* method generates **InvalidOperationException** with **Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.** text.
Is there a way how to tell ReactiveUI to synchronize the call automatically? I'd like to avoid having sychronization calls in the ViewModel class...

Comment: Don't think there's one, RxUI bindings assume your VM properties are in the same threading model as the view. A scheduler can help for one way bindings, but it won't be enough for 2-way.